# Limits for string arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, max

I wonder wether there is a limit for the maximum lengh of strings in arrays. I ve already checked my memory reserved for PHP (which is 128MB and therefore definitelly enough for my purposes) and am quite sure that i deteteced the actual problem:

My original array was:

```
$tabellenA = array
    (
        "userA" => array
            (
                "`id`" => "INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY",
                "`name`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`sirname`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`userName`" => "VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL",
                "`email`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",            ,
                "`password`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`country`" => "VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL",
                "`plz`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`road`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`city`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`state`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`house_number`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`country`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`timestamp`" => "DATETIME NOT NULL"


    )
);
```

and always called the Error Message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Envifood\req\Constants.php on line 19" until i cut the array after line 18 so that the code looked like:

```
    $tabellenA = array
(
    "userA" => array
        (
            "`id`" => "INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY",
            "`name`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
            "`sirname`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
            "`userName`" => "VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL"/*,
            "`email`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",            ,
            "`password`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
            "`country`" => "VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL",
            "`plz`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`road`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`city`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`state`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`house_number`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`country`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
            "`timestamp`" => "DATETIME NOT NULL"*/
        )
);
```

Therefore I expected that there has to be some kind of maximum limit for strings in arrays but i did not find any but a hint that arrays (for reading big data files/xml to arrays) can get tremendously big... Additionally other arrays of mine have three times more entries and do work! Additionally I made a text Array with those keys but different, shorter contents, which do work.

Do you see my mistake or is it just that arrays do not work with larger strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not a limit, is a comma which shouldn't be in there.

```
$tabellenA = array
    (
        "userA" => array
            (
                "`id`" => "INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY",
                "`name`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`sirname`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`userName`" => "VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL",
                "`email`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",         // , <--This little guy
                "`password`" => "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL",
                "`country`" => "VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL",
                "`plz`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`road`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`city`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`state`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`house_number`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`country`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL",
                "`timestamp`" => "DATETIME NOT NULL"


    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an excess `,` in your code at the line with `email` in it. That is causing the error. Removing that `,` will solve that error

Comment: Yup ... nothing to see here, move along ;-)

Comment: "`email`" => "VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL"[link], 
as far sa i know this ","  is necessary as more entries follow...

Comment: There is another comma on that line. Look further to the right

Comment: He probably tought his screen was dirty.

Comment: thanks you all! I got really sick about it but often the solution is pretty obvous *shame on me*..

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra comma (',') in email